# Flags and enum to make an linq anyFlags(MyFlag)

Tags: c#

this is a basic question I know , and surely a redo of some old recipe made by everyone on planet earth and beyond, but I just get so lost that I need some external advice.

I have an enum like this one :

```
[Flags]
    public enum MyEnum
    { 
        none=0,  //0000
        toto=1,  //0001
        tata=2,  //0010
        tati=4,  //0100
        titi=8   //1000
    }
```

and I have an enum value which is like :

```
MyEnum s= tata | titi; //(1010)
```

so as to say from what I understood s=10

Now I have a value in my database wich is a short and might be one of these , ie: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15

```
id     EnumValue
1      3
2      14
3      10
4      9
5      0
```

Now I need to get a linq statement to say which id have at least one othe enum given in s.

I would need at the end :1,2,3,4.

I have done so for theses method :

```
public static bool HasAllFlags(this short input, Enum matchTo)
{
    return (Convert.ToUInt32(input) & Convert.ToUInt32(matchTo)) == Convert.ToUInt32(matchTo);
}

public static bool IsFlag(this short input, Enum matchTo)
{
    return Convert.ToUInt32(input)== Convert.ToUInt32(matchTo);
}
```

but I am stuck with this one :

```
 public static bool HasAnyFlags(this short input, Enum matchTo)
        {
            return ....????....;
        }
```

They work pretty well , but I now I need this method which would give me 1,2,3,4 as the desired result. I have tried quite a few things but I cannot get it right. Has any of you any solutions ready made for this?

Thanks in advance,

PS: I am using c# 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your `HasAllFlags` method. It performs a bitwise AND on the test value and the required value. The result of this will be a value where each bit is set if-and-only-if it is set in the test value AND it is a required value. By checking this result value against the set of *all* required flags, you get your answer.

However, this same result value can also be used to check if *any* of the required flags were present. If *any* of the required flags were present, this result value will be non-zero. So all we need is

```
public static bool HasAnyFlags(this short input, Enum matchTo)
{
    return (Convert.ToUInt32(input) & Convert.ToUInt32(matchTo)) 
             != Convert.ToUInt32(0);
}
```

(Note that the behaviour if `matchTo` is `0` might not be what you expect)

Examples (in binary):

```
input    101010
matchTo  001100
result   001000 -> nonzero -> true

input    101010
matchTo  010001
result   000000 -> zero -> false
```

Comment: that won't work. if the input has a flag not given in matchTo, the value of the AND will also be not zero.

Comment: @Bryan not quite with you, could you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

How about just comparing with `(Enum) 0` ?

Comment: sorry but I didn't get your answer. you mean  return (enum)0; ?

Comment: You just want to see if an enum has any flags set, right? Well, if it doesn't than the enums value will be 0.